# How to Select the Row using the Checkmark only

Tags: jquery

When I select one of the `row` in the `table` I want to select the `checkbox` only in order to make a selection of the `row only`.

When I deselect the `checkbox`, everything should changed into `default` settings for instance if I select the row that has a  and then I deselect checkbox, it should to be  not  depends on what row you have selected.

**how to do that?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rowclick4 tr')
    .filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)')
    .addClass('selected')
    .end()
    .click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected td
{
 background-color: #48507b;
 color: #fff;;
}

.rowclick td
{
 padding: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #999
}

.OddRow
{
 background-color: #f0f0ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="rowclick" id="rowclick4">
  <tbody>
    <tr class = "OddRow">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes"></td>
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes" ></td>
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class = "OddRow">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes"></td>
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're logic needs a little bit of revising—instead of filtering at runtime, perform the filtering within the click event.

Comment: Not very clear about what you want there. Could you please explain more clearly what you are after and what problem you are facing? From what I could gather, it seems you are wanting something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jcftsazk/1/ ?

Comment: You have the answer Abhitalks